# how do you install Veins 5a1 on Windows 7? and connect it with Matlab

Tags: matlab, omnet++, veins

My Os is windows 7, and I am trying to connect veins with Matlab as described in the link https://github.com/veins/veins_matlab, but I face some issue.

1- I am trying to use same program versions in the above link
Veins 5a1
OMNeT++ 5.4.1
but I can't build veins correctly it's given me a lot of errors. as shown in below pic.
[image]

2- I am already done with my veins scenario and everything work nicely using the following version
( Omnet++ v 5.1 ,Veins v 4.7.1, INET v 3.6.4, SUMO v 0.30.0 ), I am trying to connect it with Matlab but an error occurred
(./veins_matlab/veins_matlab.h:23:25: fatal error: veins/veins.h: No such file or directory
 #include "veins/veins.h").

**Questions:**

1- How can I  install Veins 5a1 on OMNET 5.4.1 (Windows 7) without errors, and which INeT version should I use?

2- If there is no way to use veins 5a1, OMNET 5.4.1 on Windows 7, cann I connect Matlab with ( Omnet++ v 5.1 ,Veins v 4.7.1, INET v 3.6.4, SUMO v 0.30.0 )? and How?

Comment: You say "I can't build veins correctly it's given me a lot of errors". It's hard to help you troubleshoot these errors without knowing what they are. Most likely, the first error message is enough to help. Can you please edit your question to include this?

Comment: sure.@ChristophSommer

Answer (score 0):

You have opened both the `veins_inet` (for INET 4.0.0) and the `veins_inet3` (for INET 3.6.4) subproject of Veins 5a1 in your workspace. Pick only one (depending on your INET version) and close (or delete) the other.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but this solution can't solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I've seen the solution work for some other people. With no new info about what is different on your machine, I am afraid I cannot be of any help.